# Fire On Div ID - Google Tag Manager - Page View

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a div id called "btnConfirm" and this is the checkout completion page.

I want to fire this when the page loads and sees the Div ID. I'm assuming I chose PageView and then setup a trigger.

How can I set this up correctly?
Dom Element?
Custom Javascript?
Custom Event?

Comment: Off topic, as it should be in Webmasters. But to comment, one method would be to set up a custom JS tag that fires on your checkout completion page and traverses up the DOM to see if the ancestor of the clicked element is "btnConfirm".

Comment: How about if you just wanted to fire up the tag based on a class name if it was present? then fire google tags? how would that look?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, too. That would require a custom HTML tag.

Comment: on my order complete page I have an id called "orderComplete" I'm using a dom element id called orderComplete and then equals to the text in that orderComplete div "thank you for shopping with us. But it's not firing and the string just says "null' in the debug. can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Just curious, why are you doing it that way and not going by the page URL?

Comment: because the url doesn't change it's a netsuite application for site builder and the url doesn't give me anything to pull from. So what I'm wanting to do is just put a div with an ID and have the scripts fire on page view. just can't seem to set it up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you may want to do is to set up a tag to push an event onto the dataLayer, that will in turn trigger your tag. Set up a custom HTML tag to fire on all pages. In the tag, you just need to check for the presence of the orderComplete ID:

```
<script>
   (function(){
      if ($('div#btnConfirm #orderComplete').length > 0){ // assuming you are using jQuery
         dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'form completed'
         });
      }
   })();
</script>
```

Then create another tag to track the event, and that tag would fire when {{event}} equals 'form completed'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Javascript variable to check if the element is on page and return "true" if it is. Than you can use a combination of two rules in the trigger for your tag: 1) event equals gtm.dom 2) {{your macro}} equals true.